# ¿Cómo cuentan los votos en una elección a moderador?

Tags: soporte, elecciones

En una elección a moderador, los votos son contabilizados utilizando el Método Meek de voto único transferible (VUT).

**Referencias:**

1. [Voto único transferible](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voto_%C3%BAnico_transferible) (Wikipedia)
2. [Counting single transferable votes - Secondary preferences for prior winners - Meek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek.27s_method) (en.wikipedia)
3. [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/304899) (MSE)
4. [Single Transferable Vote by Meek's Method](http://www.dia.govt.nz/diawebsite.NSF/Files/meekm/%24file/meekm.pdf) (The Department of Internal Affairs, NZ)
5. [OpaVote](https://www.opavote.com/) (sistema utilizado para el recuento en SE)
6. [Meek STV Explained](http://blog.opavote.com/2017/04/meek-stv-explained.html) (descripción en OpaVote)

¿Alguien me puede explicar en concreto, y específicamente para la elección de Stack Overflow en español, cómo es que funciona este método?

Comment: Entiendo que es el mismo método que en todas las elecciones de [se], ¿no? Con eliminación de candidatos y repartición de sus votos.

Comment: @fedorqui casi toda la información está en inglés, y bastante desordenada. El artículo de MSE no me convence del todo. El método no es el más convencional. Realmente creo que yo no soy bueno para explicarlo de una forma clara, y vendría bien que esté explicado para las elecciones. Me gustaría que otro con mejor habilidad que yo lo pueda explicar, y me refería a la elección de SOes para definir el alcance de la pregunta (si en una respuesta se quiere dar datos de cantidad de votantes o algo similar, puede usar los actuales).

Comment: Una versión reducida de lo que he entendido (que no sé si es correcto) - la idea es que los votos no son como los que estamos acostumbrados, es un voto "fraccionado" que sigue un proceso iterativo. Eliges una serie de candidatos en orden de preferencia y, si tu primera elección gana, el sobrante de sus votos pasa proporcionalmente a tu siguiente candidato, y así sucesivamente. Luego puedo poner una respuesta... o traducir directamente algunas de las de Meta SE si así queda más claro.

Comment: Al final intenté hacer un resumen de lo que entendí. Si no está claro, dímelo y hago una traducción de alguna de las respuestas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voy a intentar explicarlo a partir de las respuestas de una [pregunta similar en Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english). Supongo que el método para Stack Overflow en Español va a ser similar al del resto de sitios de la red de Stack Exchange.

> Resumiendo (muchísimo): la idea es que los votos no son como los que estamos acostumbrados, es un voto "fraccionado" que sigue un proceso iterativo. Un voto no es `1` voto, es `1.00` voto. Eliges una serie de candidatos en orden de preferencia y, si tu primera elección gana, el sobrante proporcional de sus votos (que ya no será `1.00` sino `0.xx`) pasa a tu siguiente candidato, y así sucesivamente hasta que todos los puestos sean cubiertos.

Pero eso es una simplificación, porque sólo ocurriría así en un caso ideal en el que todos los candidatos salen elegidos directamente o de manera iterativa sin complicaciones... Pero pueden darse casos especiales como por ejemplo, que ningún candidato llegue al mínimo número de votos requerido (en cuyo caso se eliminaría al usuario con menos votos y se volverían a recontar los votos).

Éste sería el diagrama de flujo que sigue la elección:

[image: Cómo funciona la elección]

Parece simple, ¿verdad? Vamos a verlo paso a paso para comprobar que no es tan simple como parece y que en realidad es un proceso bastante complicado. Todo empieza con los electores seleccionando sus 3 candidatos favoritos por orden de preferencia, y luego...

**1- Calcular cuota para ser elegido**

La cuota es el mínimo número de votos que son necesarios para que un candidato sea elegido matemáticamente. Existen varios modos de calcular la cuota, [según la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voto_%C3%BAnico_transferible#Establecimiento_de_la_cuota), uno de los más comunes es la cuota Droop:

[image: formular cuota Droop]

Aunque, por lo que pone [Pops en su respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77560/274671), parece que en SE se usa un método un poco diferente:

[image: Formula cuota SE]

La respuesta de Pops no incluye un +1 al final, pero me imagino que debe estar ahí porque es necesario para evitar posibles bloqueos... aunque realmente no hace falta que sea un +1 basta con decir "mayor que" la cuota.

> Cómo se calcula la cuota es algo que explica Pops en su respuesta con diferentes fórmulas matemáticas. Aunque quizás sea demasiado técnico:
>
> La proporción de la cuota sobre el número total de votos que un candidato obtiene se llama el peso del candidato (o *w*). Por ejemplo, si el candidato A consigue 100 voto y la cuota es es 25, entonces *w<sub>a</sub>* será 25/100, or 1/4.
>
> Imaginemos que tu primera elección fue el candidato A, después el candidato B y finalmente el candidato C. Entonces así es como se distribuirían tus votos asumiendo que tus candidatos no son eliminados:
>
> A: *w<sub>a</sub>*  
> B: (1 - *w<sub>a</sub>*) *w<sub>b</sub>*  
> C: (1 - *w<sub>a</sub>*) (1 - *w<sub>b</sub>*) *w<sub>c</sub>*  
> exceso: (1 - *w<sub>a</sub>*) (1 - *w<sub>b</sub>*) (1 - *w<sub>c</sub>*)
>
> ¿Qué pasaría si B es eliminado?What if B got eliminated? Así sería el ajuste:
>
> A: *w<sub>a</sub>*  
> B: 0  
> C: (1 - *w<sub>a</sub>*) *w<sub>c</sub>*  
> exceso: (1 - *w<sub>a</sub>*) (1 - *w<sub>c</sub>*)

El exceso sería el número de votos que se "pierde" porque un candidato es eliminado. En la primera pasada, sería 0.

La cuota debe calcularse en cada ronda, porque variará con el número de votantes, el exceso y posiciones que haya disponibles en cada pasada... eso es uno de los motivos por los que es necesario un ordenador para este algoritmo.

**2- Contar votos**

Esto es sencillo en la primera pasada, en las siguientes no hace falta hacer mucho porque los votos sobrantes caen "en cascada" sobre los candidatos que quedan conforme se van eliminando candidatos de la lista (bien porque sean elegidos o bien porque sean "descalificados").

**3- ¿Algún candidato iguala o supera la cuota?**

Aquí empieza la parte divertida. Pueden darse dos casos:

- **Sí**, uno (o más candidatos) superó la cuota: esos candidatos han sido elegidos. ¡Enhorabuena! Si se cubren todos los puestos, genial: la elección se acaba... pero si no, se toma el sobrante de votos del candidato elegido, se divide por el número de votos que consiguió, y se pasan esos votos al siguiente candidato de los electores. Esto se hace así para que ninguna parte del voto sea perdida.

  Un ejemplo: la cuota es 10, y el candidato A consigue 15 votos. Entonces lo que se hace es que el exceso de votos (5), se divide por el total de gente que votó esa opción (15) y el resultado (0.33) se pasa al siguiente candidato de la lista de esos votantes.

  Esto se hace así porque si simplemente se eliminara el candidato sin pasar los votos a los siguientes candidatos, se les estaría quitando "poder de elección" a los votantes (encima a los que eligieron "bien" teóricamente).

  ...Y se vuelve al punto 1.
- **No**, ningún candidato llega a la cuota: entonces el usuario con menos votos es "descalificado" y eliminado de la lista de candidatos. Los votos (completos o parciales, ver arriba) que ese candidato tuviera, pasan al siguiente candidato de cada uno de sus votantes.

  ...Y se vuelve al punto 1.

Es decir, en todas las rondas se acabará repartiendo exceso de votos: o bien porque se eligió un candidato, o bien porque se eliminó un candidato.

Así un votante siempre tendrá (una fracción de) votos para entregar. Con la excepción de si todos los candidatos de un votante han sido elegidos o eliminados, entonces cualquier fracción de votos que le quede, se pierde.

El proceso termina cuando se elijan a todos los representantes (si al eliminar uno, quedan tantos como puestos disponibles, esos candidatos obtendrán el puesto automáticamente).

---

## Ejemplos

Voy a poner una serie de ejemplos, si me equivoco con las matemáticas, por favor corregidme. Vamos a imaginar que hay:

- 20 personas votando
- 5 candidatos (A, B, C, D, E)
- 3 puestos

Eso quiere decir que (usando la función de Pops, que coincide con Droop en la primera ronda) si un candidato llega a  6 votos (20/4+1) o más, entonces saldrá matemáticamente elegido, porque el resto de candidatos tendrán igual o menos votos.

### Caso 1: Elección directa en primera ronda

Algo que es improbable, pero que podría ocurrir. Se vota y se obtienen los siguientes resultados:

- Candidato A: 7 votos
- Candidato B: 6 votos
- Candidato C: 0 votos
- Candidato D: 1 votos
- Candidato E: 6 votos

Los candidatos A, B y E ganan las elecciones, no hay necesidad de segunda ronda.

### Caso 2: Elección en n rondas

Mismo escenario, pero ahora la cosa no va a ser tan sencilla, así que vamos a necesitar conocer los votos de todos:

```
Votante         | g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
----------------|----------------------------------------
Preferencia #1  | A C E A A B A B C A D E C A D B B B A A
Preferencia #2  | B A B C D C D E A D B B A B E C D E B D
Preferencia #3  | D D D D E D E A D E A D B E A A C D E C
```

La cuota inicial es 6 (20/4+1), y los resultados fueron:

- Candidato A: 8 votos
- Candidato B: 5 votos
- Candidato C: 3 votos
- Candidato D: 2 votos
- Candidato E: 2 votos

El candidato A ha sido elegido con 8 votos. Como sólo necesitaba 6/8, el exceso de 2/8 se divide proporcionalmente entre los candidatos de los votantes `g`, `j`, `k`, `m`, `p`, `t`, `y` y `z`. Cada uno obtendrá 0.25 más, con lo que ahora los votos quedarían:

```
Votante         | g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
----------------|----------------------------------------
Preferencia #1  | - C E - - B - B C - D E C - D B B B - -
Preferencia #2  | B - B C D C D E - D B B - B E C D E B D   voto vale 0.25 si guión arriba
Preferencia #3  | D D D D E D E - D E - D B E - - C D E C
```

Y los resultados serían:

- Candidato B: 5.75 votos
- Candidato C: 3.25 votos
- Candidato D: 3.00 votos
- Candidato E: 2.00 votos

Pasamos a la siguiente ronda (iteramos en el ciclo de votación). Siguiendo las indicaciones de Pops, parece que en Stack Overflow, la cuota no cambia a no ser que todos los candidatos de un votante hayan sido elegidos/eliminados (porque entonces el número de votantes cambia). Así que la cuota se mantiene en 6.

Ninguno de los candidatos llega a ese número, por lo que se elimina el candidato con menos votos: E. El siguiente candidato de la gente que le votó (`i` y `r`) recibe el sobrante (1.00 en este caso). En ambos casos era B, así que el candidato B recibe +2.

```
Votante         | g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
----------------|----------------------------------------
Preferencia #1  | - C - - - B - B C - D - C - D B B B - -
Preferencia #2  | B - B C D C D - - D B B - B - C D - B D
Preferencia #3  | D D D D - D - - D - - D B - - - C D - C
```

Y los resultados quedarían:

- Candidato B: 7.75 votos
- Candidato C: 3.25 votos
- Candidato D: 3.00 votos

Pasamos a la siguiente ronda, la cuota se mantiene igual (6), y ahora sí hay un candidato que la supera: B. El candidato B ha sido elegido, se elimina de la lista de candidatos y su sobrante, pasa a los siguientes candidatos de `g`, `i`, `l`, `n`, `r`, `t`, `v`, `w`, `x` e `y`. En el caso de `n`, `t` e `y`, el sobrante se va a perder (exceso). En el caso de `g`, `i` y `r` se debe tener en cuenta que el sobrante no se calcula sobre 1.00, sino sobre la fracción de puntos que les quedaban (de los sobrantes de A).

Como a algunos votantes ya no les quedan votos, hay que recalcular la cuota, que sería 17/4 + 1 = 5.25. Y así quedarían los votos tras la ronda previa:

```
Votante         | g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
----------------|----------------------------------------
Preferencia #1  | - C - - - - - - C - D - C - D - - - - -
Preferencia #2  | - - - C D C D - - D - - - - - C D - - D
Preferencia #3  | D D D D - D - - D - - D - - - - C D - C
```

Y los resultados serían estos:

- Candidato C: 3.442 votos
- Candidato D: 4.272 votos

Como ninguno de los dos candidatos llega a la cuota, se elimina el candidato con menos votos y tan sólo queda uno (el candidato D) que sale elegido automáticamente. Con eso se cubren todos los puestos y la elección concluye. Los candidatos elegidos fueron A, B y D.

> Nota: usando la formula de la respuesta de Pops, la cuota en la última ronda era 4.25, que haría que el candidato D saliera directamente de entre esos dos.

---

Y ese es un proceso sencillo para elegir candidato (espero no haberme equivocado en las cuentas). Ahora imagina que en lugar de haber 20 votantes, 5 candidatos y 3 puestos, es como en Stack Overflow en inglés donde hay decenas de miles de votantes, docenas de candidatos y 3-4 puestos. Sin un ordenador que calcule todo el proceso, sería una locura.

Comment: En realidad es un método bastante común, creo. En México se conoce como [_"Resto Mayor"_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Método_del_resto_mayor)  y se usa el cociente Hare para repartir curules de Senadores y Diputados Federales y Locales en las 32 entidades federativas y en la elección de la Asamblea Constituyente de la Ciudad de México (antes D. F), aunque aquí se usa el cociente Droop (yo prefiero el Hare).

Comment: Parece un método bastante complejo para ser sincero, aunque más justo en el sentido de que los votantes "exprimen" más su voto

Comment: @toledano SE es el único lugar en el que voté que haya utilizado este método. Aunque, si te interesa responder, creo que a esta pregunta le puede venir bien más de un punto de vista para explicarlo.

Comment: Definitivamente es el mismo método en todo SE. Y el argumento de que es una elección más justa me parece importantísimo.

Comment: Interesante ver que en el ejemplo A es de Alvaro ;)